# How to not let Graph's xAxis given a data to not stop at the right most

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I want to give an array of data, and if it's not equal to timeStamp's count, then the line graph will not be displayed all the way to the right side. I gave it 11 data and for some reason it would always reach all the way to the right. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Here are my codes so far

```
import Charts

struct Stock {
    var timestamp: Int
    var price: Double
}

class ChartsVC: UIViewController {

//MARK: Properties
    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
    var time: [Double] = [9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6]
    let timeStamps: [String] = ["9:00", "9:05", "9:10", "9:15", "9:20", "9:25", "9:30", "9:35", "9:40", "9:45", "9:50", "9:55", "10:00",  "10:05", "10:10", "10:15", "10:20", "10:25", "10:30", "10:35", "10:40", "10:45", "10:50", "10:55", "11:00", "11:05", "11:10", "11:15", "11:20", "11:25", "11:30", "11:35", "11:40", "11:45",  "11:50", "11:55", "12:00", "12:05", "12:10", "12:15", "12:20", "12:25", "12:30", "12:35", "12:40", "12:45", "12:50", "12:55","1:00", "1:05", "1:10", "1:15", "1:20", "1:25", "1:30", "1:35", "1:40", "1:45", "1:50", "1:55", "2:00", "2:05", "2:10", "2:15", "2:20", "2:25", "2:30", "2:35", "2:40", "2:45", "2:50", "2:55", "3:00", "3:05", "3:10", "3:15", "3:20", "3:25", "3:30", "3:35", "3:40", "3:45", "3:50", "3:55", "4:00", "4:05", "4:10", "4:15", "4:20", "4:25", "4:30", "4:35", "4:40", "4:45", "4:50", "4:55", "5:00", "5:05", "5:10", "5:15", "5:20", "5:25", "5:30", "5:35", "5:40", "5:45", "5:50", "5:55", "6:00"]
    let prices: [Double] = [24.0, 39, 0.8, -10, -13, -25, -90, 50, 64, 32, 43]

    @IBOutlet weak var chartView: LineChartView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var stocks: [Stock] = []
        for i in 0..<prices.count {
            let stock = Stock(timestamp: i+9, price: prices[i])
            stocks.append(stock)
        }
        setChartView(entriesData: stocks)
    }

    func setChartView(entriesData: [Stock]) { //version 2
        var chartEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
        var xStrings: [String] = []
        let sortedentriesData = entriesData.sorted { (s1: Stock, s2: Stock) -> Bool in //sort by timestamp
            return s1.timestamp < s2.timestamp
        }
        for (i, stock) in sortedentriesData.enumerated() {
            let newStock = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: stock.price)
            chartEntries.append(newStock)
            xStrings.append(String(stock.timestamp))
        }
        let set: LineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: chartEntries, label: "$")
        set.setColor(NSUIColor.blue, alpha: CGFloat(1))
        set.circleColors = [NSUIColor.blue]
        set.circleRadius = 3
        set.mode = LineChartDataSet.Mode.linear

        let data: LineChartData = LineChartData(dataSet: set)
        self.chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(block: { (index, axis) -> String in
            return String(self.timeStamps[Int(index)])
        })
        self.chartView.xAxis.axisMaxLabels = timeStamps.count
        self.chartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(timeStamps.count, force: true)
        self.chartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom 
        self.chartView.data = data
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you scale it properly to have the effect that I want

```
chartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(timeStamps.count)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```